# 2.8 Snapping Tool features missing?

Tags: interface

Just started to use 2.8,but im pretty new to blender in general.I was searching on 2.8 for,as Blenders manual says,"Additional Snapping Tools",but no way i can find them.Have they been moved or something ? Thx in advance
[image]

This next pic is all i see on mine

[image]

Comment: Has became snapping options, depending of which snapping is selected. Try snap to face for instance, you'll see align rotation

Comment: Thats it thank you!